# Binary tree pointer to the root needs to be referenced and dereferenced. Why?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, binary-tree, dereference

My question is why do I need to dereference and reference a pointer for the following code to work? Doesn't ref/deref cancel each other?
I would really appreciate if anyone could explain it like I'm five :)

Code:

```
template <typename T> 
class binNode {
private:
    T key;
public:
    binNode * left;
    binNode * right;
    binNode * parent;
    binNode() {
        this->left = NULL;
        this->right = NULL;
        this->parent = NULL;
    }
    // arg constructor:
    binNode (T key) {
        this->key = key;
        this->left = NULL;
        this->right = NULL;
        this->parent = NULL;
    }

    T getKey() {
        return this->key;
    }
    void setKey(T key) {
        this->key = key;
    }
};

template<typename T> class Tree {
private:
    binNode <T> *root;
public:
    Tree() {
        this->root = NULL;
    }
    Tree(binNode <T> * node) {
        node->parent = NULL;
        this->root = node;
    }
    /* THIS IS THE PART I  DON'T GET */
    void addNode(binNode<T> *&x, binNode<T> * node) { // what's up with the *&???
        if (x == NULL) {
            x = node;
            return;
        } else if (x->getKey() == node->getKey()) {
            node->left = x;
            node->parent = x->parent;
            x->parent = node;
            return;
        }

        if (node->getKey() < x->getKey()) {
            addNode(x->left, node);
        } else {
            addNode(x->right, node);
        }

    }

    void addNode(binNode<T> * node) {
        addNode(this->root, node);
    }

    binNode<T> * treeSearch(binNode<T> * x, T key) {
        if (x == NULL || key == x->getKey()) {
            return x;
        }
        if (key < x->getKey()) {
            return treeSearch(x->left, key);
        } else {
            return treeSearch(x->right, key);
        }
    }

    void printOrdered() {
        inorderTreeWalk(root);
        cout << endl;
    }

    void inorderTreeWalk(binNode<T> * node) {
        if (node != NULL) {
            inorderTreeWalk(node->left);
            cout << node->getKey() << '\t';
            inorderTreeWalk(node->right);
        }
    }

};
```

Here is the main function (`#inlude` is not included)

```
int main() {
    Tree<int> T (new binNode<int>(10));
    // Tree<int> T = new binNode<int>(10);

    T.addNode(new binNode<int> (11));
    T.addNode(new binNode<int> (9));
    T.addNode(new binNode<int> (8));
    T.addNode(new binNode<int> (12));

    T.printOrdered();

}
```

Comment: Note: you might want to learn about *smart* pointers, such as `std::unique_ptr` (C++11 required), because here I am pretty sure your code leaks memory.

Comment: +1 to Matthieu. If C++11 is not available, [Boost smart pointers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) provide an alternative.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not a reference / dereference *of a pointer*, it's a reference *to* a pointer. It is necessary because...

```
void addNode(binNode<T> *&x, binNode<T> * node) {
    if (x == NULL) {
        x = node; // ...here...
        return;
    } else // ...
```

...you are *assigning* to the parameter `x`.

If you hadn't passed the pointer `x` *by reference*, you would assign to the local copy of the parameter:

```
void addNode(binNode<T> * x, binNode<T> * node) {
    if (x == NULL) {
        x = node; // this acts on the local copy only, and thus does nothing.
        return;
    } else // ...
```

Comment: God... All those pointers, pointers to pointers, references to pointers... I guess it's time to go to bed! Thank you very much! I think I understand it a little better now :)

Comment: @RafazZ: You get used to it. Once you do, *having* them is a real nice win. (And don't forget `&&`, C++11's "rvalue reference". It allows to provide special copy constructors and assignment operators for the case of the "source" object being an "rvalue"; i.e., a temporary. They allow for more efficient "move semantics" for this case, i.e. *moving* data members from the temporary to your object instead of having to deep-copy them.) Besides, well-designed code should use "naked" pointers only very, very sparingly. That's what Matthieu pointed at in his comment.

Answer (score 0):

Via the pointer (without the reference), you get a local copy of the address. Which means you can manipulate the value behind the pointer (in this case *x) which would change. But if you change the address itself, the address would behave like a local copy and you lose the address-changes after leaving the method.